# Несобственно-прямая речь

Tags: лингвистика

ФРАЗА ПОСЛЕ ДИАЛОГА. МОЖЕТ НАЗЫВАТЬСЯ НЕСОБСТВЕННО-ПРЯМОЙ РЕЧЬЮ? Я ДУМАЮ, ДА. КАК ВЫ ДУМАЕТЕ? НАПРИМЕР: 
– И  просто грех не удивить чем-нибудь такого приятного парня! — воскликнул Димка.
- Мысль интересная, — сказал Петька.
- Пошли, — поманил Гриша всю компанию в сторону. — Я знаю хорошее укромненькое местечко. Там все и обсудим.
***Ребята двинулись следом за Гришкой. Он, обогнув стороной спальные корпуса, вывел их к скамейке, которая пряталась за деревьями***.

Answer (score 2):

Не плодите сущностей. 
Зачем придумывать неизвестного науке зверя для обычного авторского текста?

Несобственно-прямая речь по сути эта та же прямая, только в кавычки не взятая. Разве ваш фрагмент передаёт речь (или мысли) одного из персонажей?

Answer (score 1):

Краткая характеристика. 
Несобственно-прямая речь --- форма передачи чужой речи, в которой повествование ведется от лица автора и в то же время в авторскую речь вводятся лексические и грамматические элементы, свойственные речи персонажа...
Пример несобственно-прямой речи:
Надя Извекова устроила свой чемодан под окном в купе. Поезд уже разогнался  и лихо тараторил на стыках. Окрестные тульские домишки ускользали порывами, то кучно, то вразброс, как ветреным днем отсохшие листья с дерева. Так  и должно быть. Уносилось, исчезало прошлое. Неужели --- исчезало? Ну, до известной степени. Чуть-чуть... И неужели у Нади уже есть какое-то прошлое? Что значит какое-то (улыбнулась она своему вопросу)? Просто отличное...

Comment: И что дальше? Вы считаете, что рассматриваемый фрагмент представляет собой *форму передачи чужой речи*?  
Вообще хотелось бы помимо методических соображений видеть и ответ на конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Нет в выделенном фрагменте никакой чужой речи.

Answer (score 0):

Ребята двинулись следом за Гришкой. Он, обогнув стороной спальные корпуса, вывел их к скамейке, которая пряталась за деревьями.

Если речь идет об этих фразах, то это слова автора. Они не являются несобственно-прямой речью.

Несобственно-прямая речь.

В русском языке существует особый способ передачи чужой речи, который содержит в себе особенности как прямой речи, так и косвенной речи. Это несобственно-прямая речь (Н-ПР). Прием НП-Р введен в русскую литературу А.С. Пушкиным и получил широчайшее развитие в художественной литературе.

Специфика ее заключается в следующем: она сохраняет особенности речи говорящего – лексико-фразеологические, эмоционально-оценочные, как и ПР; с другой стороны, как и в КР, в ней выдерживаются правила замены личных местоимений и личных глаголов.

Н-ПР состоит в том, что автор как бы перевоплощается в своего героя и говорит за него, передавая от себя мысли героя, его «внутреннюю речь».
Синтаксической особенностью Н-ПР является невыделенность ее в составе речи авторской.
Н-ПР не оформляется как придаточная часть (в отличие от косвенной) и не вводится специальными вводящими словами (в отличие от ПР). Она не имеет типизированной синтаксической форы. Это чужая речь, непосредственно включенная в авторское повествование, которая сливается с ним и не отграничивается от него.

Н-ПР ведется обычно не от имени лица, а от имени автора, рассказчика, чужая речь воспроизводится в речи автора с присущими ей особенностями, но в  то же время не выделяется на фоне авторской речи:
Ср.:
ПР – Друзья побывали в театре и в один голос заявили: «Очень уж понравился нам этот спектакль».
КР – Друзья побывали в театре и в один голос заявили, что им очень  понравился этот спектакль.
Н-ПР – Друзья побывали в театре. Очень уж понравился им  этот спектакль.

Н-ПР – стилистическая фигура экспрессивного синтаксиса. Широко используется в художественной литературе как прием сближения авторского повествования с речью героев. Это позволяет сохранить естественные интонации и нюансы ПР и вместе с тем дает возможность не отграничивать резко эту речь от авторского повествования.
В художественной литературе часто Н-ПР употребляется в виде 2 части бессоюзного сложного предложения и отражает реакцию действующего лица на воспринимаемое им явление, напр.:
Ах, как хорошо было участковому Анискину! Поглядел на ситцевые занавески – эх, какие веселые! Потрогал ногой коврик – эх, какой важный! Вздохнул комнатные запахи – ну, как в детстве…